# Reducing Time Complexity of Function That Determines the Element in the Array That Has an Odd Number of Occurrences

Tags: c++, xcode, testing

I would like to reduce the time complexity for this function that is supposed to take a vector like the following:

A=[30,15,12,15,15,12,30]

and output 15, the element that occurs an odd number of times.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A)
{
    int value=0;
    int count=0;
        
    vector<vector<int>> B;
    
    for (int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<A.size(); j++)
        {
            if (A[i]==A[j])
                count++;
        }
        if (i==0)
        {
            B.push_back({count, A[i]});
        }
        else
        {
            for (int x=0; x<B.size(); x++)
            {
                if (B[x][1]==A[i])
                    break;
                else if(x==(B.size()-1))
                {
                    B.push_back({count, A[i]});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<B.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((B[i][0]%2)!=0)
            value = B[i][1];
    }

    return value;
}
```

This is to practice for a coding interview and gave me a performance of 25%.

Comment: What do you know about the `^` operator?

Comment: what is the currenct complexity? What complexity do you need it to have?

Comment: Will you only ever have one value with an odd number of elements in the vector?

Comment: I'd just insert all elements into a `std::map` (the value of the map being the counts) and then iterate over the map. But even if you wanted to stick to your current method of tracking everything in a single vector with (count, value), I'd use a `vector<pair<int, int>>` instead of `vector<vector<int>>`, because that avoids a lot of unnecessary allocations...

Comment: @Codo `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- Every example on that page except for one has that monstrousity in it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the many reasons that coding interviews are inherently broken is that you are expected to simply have a set of algorithms memorized that you can write on demand. This one requires knowing the behavior of XOR (exclusive or).

Simply put:

```
A | B | A^B
-----------
0 | 0 | 0
- | - | -
0 | 1 | 1
- | - | - 
1 | 0 | 1
- | - | -
1 | 1 | 0
```

The gist is that any value XOR'd with itself is 0. So if a value A is XOR'd with itself an odd number of times, the result is A.

This means that all values that occur an even amount of times will cancel each other out, and the only value left will be the one that occurred an odd number of times.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int solution(std::vector<int> const& A)
{
  int occursOddNumberOfTimes = 0;

  for (const auto& i : A) {
    occursOddNumberOfTimes ^= i;
  }

  return occursOddNumberOfTimes;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{30, 15, 12, 15, 15, 12, 30};

  std::cout << solution(v) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
15
```

The performance of this algorithm is O(N), as it only needs to traverse the original vector once. The space complexity is also O(N), as no extra containers are needed, just the original vector.

Comment: Then when the interviewer gets the idea that this was memorized from some coding websites, they will ask "what if the items are strings and not integers, or floating point values?"  Then the interviewee just got broken.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Note the table is for bits and then the principle is applied to the bits of the `int`s. The interviewee can explain that it works with strings and floats as well ;)

Comment: This still works for floating point values AFAIK. For strings, you might still be able to get away with this algorithm as-is. If not, a hash might be determined to be sufficient enough. I've also found it pretty rare that interviewers care that much. As long as you can explain the algorithm itself, you're good to go. I don't agree with this method of interviewing. You can show a candidate a more complex piece of code and ask them explain what it does. Being able to read code also demonstrates knowledge, and can demonstrate it a lot better than these dumb questions.

Comment: @sweenish floating point types do not support `operator ^`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good to know. It's not like anyone will find themselves having to bust this out at work anyway. Then sure, you're stuck counting and your runtime goes up to O(2N). But the question is never asked for floating point types, because they want to see *this* algorithm.

Comment: @NathanOliver https://godbolt.org/z/oz969bo3z, not sure if this is what the interviewer would want to see though ;)

Comment: I hadn't even considered casting. Maybe for the best, though.

Comment: I honestly don't think the solution with the `^` operator is an actual solution to the problem. How realistic is it to have a list of integers where exactly one element occurs an odd number of times? If the precondition isn't met, the XOR code will likely return a number that isn't even part of the list. Sure, it's a "clever" solution, but not a solution I'd want to see in production code. I'm not saying there can't ever be a place for such clever tricks, but then I'd really want to see a comment as to why a given precondition will always be true here (and why this optimization matters).

Comment: @chris_se That's overthinking the problem. If this is an interview question, that's the algorithm that's being looked for. That's all there is to it. Fun fact, with only minor tweaks, you can find two numbers that occur an odd number of times, still using XOR.

Comment: for the lolz, works with strings too https://godbolt.org/z/dEKfEq1K8. Do I get the job? :P

Comment: @sweenish Honestly, if I were to interview someone, I'd rather have someone that questions the interview problem in a meaningful manner, than have someone who's good at cramming all of the standard interview problems. The best improvements to codebases I've worked on have always come from people (even non-technical people in some cases) asking the "why?" question, instead of trying to solve the "how?" question.

Comment: @chris_se Good for you, then. That's beside the point that the interview question OP was given is explicitly seeking out this algorithm, and that's how their interview is being conducted. Which is why I have my first paragraph about how broken developer interviews are.

Comment: My takeaway so far has been that many members here are either very disconnected from the current hellscape that is developer interviews, or got lucky to work at a company that has moved beyond this format. Those companies are still a minority. Far too many here are quick jump on the "code golf bad" wagon without realizing it is basically required these days to get jobs, especially out of university. I also don't like that it's this way, but I can recognize that one has to play the game. A fresh grad really doesn't get to be choosy.

Comment: I would encourage members here to find out how their company interviews candidates if they don't know, and "be change you want to see" if it's discovered that they just expect candidates to solve leetcode problems.